# How to update profile photo on stackexchange.com (network profile)?

Tags: support, stackexchange.com, profile-picture

I have updated my profile photo in `stackoverflow.com`, but my profile photo (network profile) in `stackexchange.com` is not changed. I checked the `stackexchange.com > network profile` page to find any possible links or clue, but there weren't any.

Comment: Did you already blame [caching](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/221414#221414)?

Comment: @rene no caching, the network profile isn't auto syncing anymore.

Comment: It is permanently un-cached?